# Некорректный вывод времени JavaScript

Tags: javascript

При выводе часов, минут и секунд , от 0 и до 10 данные выводятся одиночными цифрами , то есть 23:12:5 или 23:5:20, а нужно что бы было 23:12:05 или 23:05:20
Как это реализовать?
Пробовал преобразовать все в строку и через .padStart и через .slice , но ничего нормального не получилось.

```js
function time() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
setInterval('time()', 1000);
```

```html
<h1 id="clock">
</h1>
```

Comment: `seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')`

Comment: Или `var seconds = ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения:

```
function zero_pad(input)
{
    return input >= 10 ? input : "0" + input;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = zero_pad(hours) + ":" + zero_pad(minutes) + ":"
    + zero_pad(seconds);
```

Или, как уже ответил в комментарии @andreymal

```
seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')
```

Кстати, не передавайте setInterval строку `'time()'`. Передавайте функцию:

```
setInterval(time, 1000);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!